# Javascript appears only when I call Google Developer Console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fighting with a js bug. I'm not so skilled with javascript so maybe is something obvious but I cannot find the fault.

I [publish this review](http://www.dday.it/redazione/14559/samsung-galaxy-note-4-recensione-prova-review)

At this point (search for string "Il Galaxy Note 4 permette anche una gestione") I insert a [TwentyTwenty JS plugin by Zurb](https://github.com/zurb/twentytwenty)

The plugin appear random, and It appears always when I call developer console on chrome.
I use this invocation code on document ready.

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $(".twentytwenty-container").twentytwenty();
});
```

Comment: I tried to copy this line `$(".twentytwenty-container").twentytwenty();` directly into chrome console and plugin works... so it seems that it does not run. Did you tried to comment the `$(window).load(function(){`

Comment: @MarcoMercuri I add a console log and it works... 
Sometime it appears, sometime is hidden.
If I use "analyze element" on chrome It always pop up.

Comment: You should try $(document).ready(); instead of $(window).load();, if that line is already into a $(document).ready(); just remove $(window).load().